# QueryException - Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry when I hit the route 'logout'

Tags: exception, laravel, logout, duplicates

I get the above error when I try and logout by hitting the route `/logout`. The table that is referenced in the screenshot is `mdbids`. It stores all of my IDs (strings, 16 characters in length).

[image]

When a user is created their MDBID (id) is stored in the `mdbids` table.

**routes.php**

```html
<?php

Route::get('login', ['as' => 'login', 'uses' => 'SessionsController@create']);
Route::get('logout', ['as' => 'logout', 'uses' => 'SessionsController@destroy']);
```

**SessionsController.php**

```html
<?php

use MDB\Forms\LoginForm;

class SessionsController extends \BaseController {

protected $loginForm;

function __construct(LoginForm $loginForm)
{
    $this->loginForm = $loginForm;
}

public function create()
{
if(Auth::check()) return Redirect::to("/users");
    return View::make('sessions.create');
}

public function store()
{
    $this->loginForm->validate($input = Input::only('email','password'));

    if (Auth::attempt($input)) {
        Notification::success('You signed in successfully!');
        return Redirect::intended('/');
    }
    Notification::error('The form contains some errors');
    return Redirect::to('login')->withInput()->withFlashMessage("The form contains some errors");

}

public function destroy()
{
    Auth::logout();
    return Redirect::home();
}
}
```

The following is taken from my User.php (model) file. It isn't the whole file as it is fairly big, but this is the only part where IDs are mentioned.

**User.php** (model)

```html
<?php

public function save(array $options = array())
{

    $this->mdbid = $this->mdbid ?: str_random(16);
    $this->key  = $this->key  ?: str_random(11);

    Mdbid::create([
        'mdbid'        => $this->mdbid,
        'table_number' => 7,
        'table_name'   => 'users',
        'created_at'   => Carbon::now(),
        'updated_at'   => Carbon::now()
    ]);

    parent::save($options);
}
```

I don't know where to start to look. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that the logout is actually causing save() to run, and therefor you are causing `Mdbid::create` to run with an already added key (presumably when you logged in, or somewhere else in your User model?).

## Solution #1:

You could add a `logout()` function to the `User` model that you have. Something similar to

```
function logout()
{
    $this->mdbid = null;

    return Auth::logout()
}
```

This will stop two of the same keys being added to the logout function.

---

## Solution #2

If what you are trying to accomplish is adding a row upon a successful login, then you should not be using the `User::save()` function, rather, you should be listening for the auth.login event.

Inside app/start/global.php, add the following code:

```
Event::listen('auth.login', function($user)
{
    $user->mdbid = $user->mdbid ?: str_random(16);
    $user->key  = $user->key  ?: str_random(11);

    Mdbid::create([
        'mdbid'        => $user->mdbid,
        'table_number' => 7,
        'table_name'   => 'users',
        'created_at'   => Carbon::now(),
        'updated_at'   => Carbon::now()
    ]);

});
```

This will ensure only one row gets added to Mdbid per successful login, instead of adding a new row (with the same id) each time the User model is updated.

---

## Solution #3 (a.k.a. what was really wanted)

Each table has `mdbid` as a primary key. Each primary key needs to be added to the Mdbid table each time a new row is inserted.

The way that this should be done is with an `Observer`. The first part is adding a new Observer class that will be used for all of the models we want to add the mdbid into:

```
class MdbidObserver
{
    /**
      * Observe new rows being added into the database
      */
    public function creating($model)
    {
        // note that $model could be any model
        $model->mdbid = $model->mdbid ?: str_random(16);
        $model->key   = $model->key   ?: str_random(11);

        Mdbid::create([
            'mdbid'        => $model->mdbid,
            'table_number' => 7,
            'table_name'   => 'users',
            'created_at'   => Carbon::now(),
            'updated_at'   => Carbon::now()
        ]);
    }
}
```

The second part is adding the Observer to all the models that we want the mdbid added to (inside `app/start/global.php`):

```
User::observe(new MdbidObserver);
Artist::observe(new MdbidObserver);
Album::observe(new MdbidObserver);
```

To stop any issues with mdbid not <strike>actually being random</strike> already being used, you might want to add a loop just before $model->mdbid. Something similar to:

```
$isUnique = false; 
while (!$isUnique) 
{ 
    $unqiueId = str_random(16); 

    $row = Mdbid::where('mdbid', $uniqueId); 
    if (is_object($row)) 
        $isUnique = true; 
}

$model->mdbid = $uniqueId;
```

Comment: I don't want to unset the MDBID. I just want it to be inserted into the MDBIDs table (a table that stores all of the used MDBIDs) when the user is created.

Comment: Where do I put the code to save the MDBID then? And when do I call it?

Comment: I have multiple tables, all of which have an MDBID (a universal ID - 16 character alphanumeric string) as the PK. When someone accesses the route `/{MDBID}` the MDBID is looked up in the MDBIDs table, and the appropriate view is returned. Does that make things clearer? As such, when a user registers on the site their MDBID is saved into this table.

Comment: No, it doesn't... the mdbid is being generated by random and saved into the Mdbid table per login. Maybe you want to also save the Mdbid to the user table, so you are not generating a new one each time?

Comment: I don't think you understand. The error I am receiving, I know, is caused by where I have placed the `MDBID::create...` code. I do however want to save the user's MDBID once they register (to designate that it has been taken).

Comment: Then you should add a column to your users table, and only run `Mdbid::create` if that column is null. Create the new mdbid row, save the id to the users column and you will not have this issue any more.